# Tensorflow 2.11 error: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.__internal__' has no attribute 'register_load_context_function'

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow

I had to update Tensorflow to the currently latest version 2.11. when importing i get "AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.**internal**' has no attribute 'register_load_context_function'". I have also completely reinstalled a full anaconda environment and downgraded Python to the version compatible with the latest of Tensorflow and then "pip3 install Tensorflow==2.11". Got the same error. I have no other ideas.

The full error log is the following

```
import tensorflow as tf

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_432\3752927832.py in <module>
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>
    467 if hasattr(_current_module, "keras"):
    468   try:
--> 469     _keras._load()
    470   except ImportError:
    471     pass

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\lazy_loader.py in _load(self)
     39     """Load the module and insert it into the parent's globals."""
     40     # Import the target module and insert it into the parent's namespace
---> 41     module = importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
     42     self._parent_module_globals[self._local_name] = module
     43 

~\anaconda3\envs\mltrade2\lib\importlib\__init__.py in import_module(name, package)
    124                 break
    125             level += 1
--> 126     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    127 
    128 

~\anaconda3\envs\mltrade2\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py in <module>
     19 """
     20 from keras import distribute
---> 21 from keras import models
     22 from keras.engine.input_layer import Input
     23 from keras.engine.sequential import Sequential

~\anaconda3\envs\mltrade2\lib\site-packages\keras\models\__init__.py in <module>
     16 
     17 
---> 18 from keras.engine.functional import Functional
     19 from keras.engine.sequential import Sequential
     20 from keras.engine.training import Model

~\anaconda3\envs\mltrade2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\functional.py in <module>
     32 from keras.engine import input_spec
     33 from keras.engine import node as node_module
---> 34 from keras.engine import training as training_lib
     35 from keras.engine import training_utils
     36 from keras.saving.legacy import serialization

~\anaconda3\envs\mltrade2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in <module>
     43 from keras.saving.experimental import saving_lib
     44 from keras.saving.legacy import hdf5_format
---> 45 from keras.saving.legacy import save
     46 from keras.saving.legacy import saving_utils
     47 from keras.saving.legacy import serialization

~\anaconda3\envs\mltrade2\lib\site-packages\keras\saving\legacy\save.py in <module>
     22 from keras.saving.legacy import serialization
     23 from keras.saving.legacy.saved_model import load as saved_model_load
---> 24 from keras.saving.legacy.saved_model import load_context
     25 from keras.saving.legacy.saved_model import save as saved_model_save
     26 from keras.utils import traceback_utils

~\anaconda3\envs\mltrade2\lib\site-packages\keras\saving\legacy\saved_model\load_context.py in <module>
     66 
     67 
---> 68 tf.__internal__.register_load_context_function(in_load_context)

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.__internal__' has no attribute 'register_load_context_function'
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this source](https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/error-attributeerror-module-tensorflow-compat-v2-internal-has-no-attribute-register-load-context-function/12480/7), this error may be happening because you have the Keras package installed in your environment. Try uninstalling it:

```
pip uninstall keras
pip install tensorflow==2.11
```

Comment: uninstalled keras, reinstalled tensorflow, last line of tensorflow installation log was "Successfully installed keras-2.11.0". Relunched conda environment and jupyter notebook kernel. Same error. Disperation!